# Graphite is not graphing anything for ranges bigger than 7 hours

Tags: graphite

My current retention rule is like so:

```
[whatever]
priority = 110
pattern = ^stats\.whatever\..*
retentions = 60:10080,600:262974
```

If I understand correctly, this will save 2 days of 1 minute data and 5 years of ten minute data.

I have been sending data to graphite for the last couple of hours and I can see the a graph of this data but only for ranges less than 7 hours. If I try to visualize this data for a range of, for example, 1 day, the resulting graph doesn't show a single data point.

Is this caused by my retention rule?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem; for me it wasn't the retention rules, but the aggregation rules.  By default, my counters were being assigned to `--agggregationMethod average` and `-xFilesFactor 0.5`. But my data was nowhere near that dense, so the aggregator was throwing away my data on the grounds that there wasn't a statistically significant sample available.

In my particular use case, I was interested in the peak value over some time period, so I used `whisper-resize.py` to reconfigure my database: `--aggregationMethod max`, `--xFilesFactor 0.0` gave me the behavior I was expecting.

See also [storage-aggregation.conf](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/config-carbon.html)

Answer (score 15):

I had this same problem. After you change your retention rules, you need to restart carbon-cache.py. If you want to keep the data you have you need to run whisper-resize.py on your whisper files (.wsp).

This link should help too:
https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/140289

However in that link, the parameters passed to whisper-resize.py are in the wrong order. It should be `whisper-resize.py <file> <retention rate>`

Here's a helpful command for resizing:
`find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper -type f -name "*.wsp" -exec whisper-resize.py {} <retention rate> \;`

Adjust it as needed.